# Not Getting a Calculated Value of the Constant e

Tags: c

Not really sure what the problem is here. I know I have the factorial function correct because I tested it separately. But the function that calculates e is tripping me up. All I have to do is add all the values after each factorial has been calculated. But I am having trouble translating that into C code. The problem for sure is in my second function. Any help or pointers would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NOERROR 0
#define DECIMAL_PLACES 16
#define EXPECTED_E 2.7182818284590452L

long calcFactorial(int);
double calcE(int);

long calcFactorial(int n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    sum = n;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(n != 1)
        {
            sum = sum * (n - 1);
            n = n - 1;
        }
        printf("factorial sum: %ld\n", sum);
        return sum;
    }
}

double calcE(int n)
{
    double e = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < DECIMAL_PLACES; counter++)
    {
        e = e + (1/calcFactorial(n));
        n--;
    } 

    printf("Expected e value: %0.16Lf\n", EXPECTED_E);
    printf("Calculated e value: %0.16d\n", e);

    return e;
}

int main()
{
    calcE(10);
}
```

Comment: Why is `calcE` `long` returning?

Comment: `1/calcFactorial(n)` is always 0 because of integer division.

You may change that to:

`1.0/calcFactorial(n)`

Comment: @EliSadoff right, that should be a double, or maybe even a long double.

Comment: and `calcE` doesn't even _return_ something

Comment: Note that 12! is the largest factorial that fits in a 32-bit integer; 20! is the largest factorial that fits in a 64-bit integer.

Comment: Which `e` do you mean? Euler's number is not an integer. For any reasonable approximation, you need floating point numbers. So why use integers?

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

- using `long` to store floating point result. Use `double`
- passing `n` but looping using a bigger value: `n` becomes negative after a while: infinite loop
- `e = e + (1/calcFactorial(counter));` adds 0 to `e` most of the time because `calcFactorial` returns an integer (`long`)
- `EXPECTED_E` constant had `L` suffix, which means `long`. Not what you want.

Fixed version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NOERROR 0
#define DECIMAL_PLACES 16
#define EXPECTED_E 2.7182818284590452

long calcFactorial(int);
void calcE(int);

long calcFactorial(int n)
{
    long sum = 0;
    sum = n;

    if(n == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        while(n != 1)
        {
             sum *= (n - 1);
             n = n - 1;
        }
    return sum;
    }
}

void calcE(int n)
{
    double e = 0;
    int counter = 0;

    for (counter = 0; counter < n; counter++)
    {
        e = e + (1.0/calcFactorial(counter));
    } 

    printf("Expected e value: %0.16lf\n", EXPECTED_E);
    printf("Calculated e value: %0.16lf\n", e);
}

int main( )
{
    calcE(10);
}
```

This code outputs:

```
Expected e value: 2.7182818284590451
Calculated e value: 2.7182815255731922
```

Note: you are limited to a given maximum for `n` because after that you'll overflow `long`. Maybe consider using `long long` or `unsigned long long` for the factorial part (and even with that you're severely limited).

Answer (score 1):

Jean-François Fabre highlighted your formal errors quite well, but it is not so far fetched to calculate with integers up to the final division--which must be done with floats, of course. The trick can be done with a method called [binary splitting](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/splitting.ps) and, to my own surprise, it works very well native doubles, only one decimal digit off. It is also very simple to implement (code below written with legibility in mind).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define BS_AFU 0
#define BS_AOK 1

static int exp1_bin_split(uint64_t a, uint64_t b, uint64_t *P, uint64_t *Q){
  int err = BS_AOK;

  uint64_t p1, q1, p2, q2, t1, one;
  one = 1UL;

  t1 = b - a;
  if(t1 == one){
     *P = one;
     *Q = b;
     return err;
  }
  t1 = (a + b) >> 1;

  err = exp1_bin_split(a, t1, &p1, &q1);
  if(err != BS_AOK){
    return err;
  }
  err = exp1_bin_split(t1, b, &p2, &q2);
  if(err != BS_AOK){
    return err;
  }

  *P = q2 * p1 + p2;
  *Q = q1 * q2;

  return err;
}

#include <float.h>

static int exp1(double *a){
  int err = BS_AOK;
  uint64_t p = 0UL, q = 0UL, zero = 0UL;
  double dp, dq;

  // DBL_DIG + 2 = 17 here on my machine
  // had DBL_DIG + 1 first but found out via T&E that
  // one more is still inside the precision of a binary64
  err = exp1_bin_split(zero, DBL_DIG + 2, &p, &q);
  if(err != BS_AOK){
    return err;
  }

  p = p + q;

  dp = (double) p;
  dq = (double) q;

  *a = dp/dq;

  return err;
}


int main(void){
  double e = 0.0;
  int err = BS_AOK;

  err = exp1(&e);
  if(err != BS_AOK){
    fprintf(stderr,"Something went wrong in computing e\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  printf("exp(1) ~ 2.7182818284590452353602874713526624978\nexp1   ~ %.20g\n",e);

  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

It uses the same algorithm as you do but does not compute the individual fractions and sums them up as floats but does it all at once with integers such that we have a large fraction at the end to resemble the approximation of `exp(1)`. That explanation is a bit over-simplified, please read the linked paper for the details.